# Keyboard layout panel applet in MATE 1.6

Tags: keyboard-layout, mate-desktop, gnome-panel

I'm on a system with MATE 1.6.1. I didn't find the `Keyboard Indicator Applet` in `Add to Panel` list. How can I add this applet to a panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applet is supposed to be added automatically in the Notification area once the user has set up multiple keyboards. If this doesn't happen, it is advised to remove the 2nd keyboard layout and add it back.

Comment: maybe log out and back in to see options and changes