# Keyboard layout selector is missing from the indicator applet in ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 20.04.03.

At some point in the past, it was possible to select between multiple keyboard layouts using a drop-down in the indicator-applet in the panel. This is no longer the case.

Multiple keyboard layouts are enabled on the system, but the switching option is missing.

I'd like to get this feature back, especially because I remember it including an on-screen (mouse) keyboard which is handy.

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102943/keyboard-layout-panel-applet-in-mate-1-6), but there's no way to tell whether that issue was due to the same bug. Also, that question has no valid answers, so we'll need to sort this out anew regardless.

I also [can't type backslash anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376518/i-can-no-longer-type-backslash-in-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-p50) but I think that's an unrelated issue.

Comment: please add the output of `setxkbmap -query` to the question

Answer (score 0):

This issue can arise if support for the keyboard layout's language is lost or removed. In my case, the UK language options were lost during a distribution upgrade. The Keyboard layout control panel shows the previously selected layouts, but cannot use them if the corresponding language is not also installed. This causes keyboard layout switching to fail silently. (The keyboard control panel will not warn/notify if this problem has emerged).

To resolve it, [install the languages associated with the desired keyboard layout through the "language support" control panel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1376937/89062).